# Trigger keyup on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code below I am not able to trigger the quantity function. Normally, when I execute the quantity function below I use `keyup`, i.e when I start typing in the quantity box.

However this time, in the quantity input box below I fetch a value from the database into it already so on page load I am expecting the function `trigger` to run that function. That is not working. How can I get this done?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  @foreach($products - > items as $item)
    var item = $('#{!! $item->id !!}');
    var ad = JSON.parse(item.attr('data-item'));
    if (item.prop("checked")) {
      $('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container"> ' +
        '<p  class="name" >' + ad.name + '</p>' +
        '<p  class="price" data-price="' + ad.price + '">' + ad.price + '</p>' +
        '<p class="total" ><span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p>' +
        '<input size="50" type="text" class="form-control quantity"  placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]" value="{!!$item->pivot->quantity!!}" required/>' +
        '</div>'
      )
    } else {
      $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();
    }

      quantityFunction();

  @endforeach
```

**update**

```
<script>
var quantityFunction => function() {

  var container = $(this).closest('div');
        var sum;

        var quantity = Number($(this).val());
        var price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    
        points = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.points').data('points'));  

       container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
       container.find(".pts-total span").text(quantity * points);


        sum = 0;



       $(".line-total").each(function(){
       sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
       })    
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put the quantity function into a non anonymous function and call it on document ready?

```
var quantityFunction = function() {
  // your code here
}
```

and

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  quantityFunction ();
});
```

**EDIT**

JS Snipped:

```
var quantityFunction = function() {
  var container = $(this).closest('div');
  var sum;

  var quantity = Number($(this).val());
  var price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));
  points = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.points').data('points'));

  container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
  container.find(".pts-total span").text(quantity * points);

  sum = 0;

  $(".line-total").each(function() {
    sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
  });
}
```

Comment: please check my update. this is what i have at the moment but it is not working

Comment: remove the [ and ] within the function block. => function() { not function() {[

Comment: i have removed the square bracket but it doesn't work please. look at my update

Comment: Recognised another mistake: var quantityFunction => function() has to be var quantityFunction = function()

Comment: could you please produce the snippet to be much clearer?

Comment: the code in the function is not running but then when i put an alert in the code, the alert runs.. why is this happening

Comment: I can't remote debug this for you. Is it possible, that you create a plunker? https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it have to be here?

> $('.panel').on('trigger','**click**',function() { }

Comment: why the click event?

Comment: The parameter you changed is the selector. There is no `<click>` element, so this won't have any affect

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, was your comment mine?

Comment: Dodis, i don't get how your function will do what i want

Answer (score 1):

> $('.panel').on('trigger','.quantity',function()

Which event you want to trigger on the `.panel`?

Correct format for `.on` jQuery method is

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

eg:

```
$('.panel').on('click','.quantity',function() {} );
```

Changes to your updated code,

```
    var $container = $('.panel').closest('div');
    var sum;

    var quantity = Number($('.quantity').val());
    var price = Number($container.find('.price').data('price'));    
    points = Number($container.find('.points').data('points'));  

   $container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
   $container.find(".pts-total span").text(quantity * points);
```

Comment: i fetch a number into the quantity input like in my code so on page load, the quantity function should be triggered so the code in the function runs

Comment: Your function works somehow i like i would have wanted but then i have to click on the quantity input box before the function runs but then i want the function to run once the page loads

Comment: Understood. Then you can go for scipper's answer. Your 'quantityFunction ()' will have change accordingly.

Comment: please check my update if that is correct. I have that but it is not working

Comment: Remove surrounding square brackets from your code, `var quantityFunction = function() {[ ...]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160084/discussion-between-madhavan-v-and-pogba).

Comment: I have removed the brace square bracket but wouldn't work